# Retrieve multiple values from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, crystal-reports

I have a requirement to retrieve the different values for a column (the `Comment` column).

There are two tables Followup Master and Followup Details. I want to retrieve all values from both tables(the other values are unique while the "comment" can be multiple for the same ID). I want to show all the values along with the different comment for the same ID.

I want to show these in a crystal report to the user like below.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Add table structure, sample data and expected output .

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use join:

```
select * 
from `Followup Details` 
left join `Followup Master` on `Followup Master`.ID = `Followup Details`.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1),
>   with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL
>   in the right side when there is no match.

---

`LEFT JOIN` sample in your case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Followup Details]     AS fd
LEFT JOIN [Followup Master] AS fm
ON fd.ID = fm.ID
```

Comment: I want to show all the values from a particular column only. The rest of the values remain the same. My scenario is :- There is a comment column which has different values in different row, while the user id, amount,age remains the same. So i do not want them to be shown.

Comment: Update your question please with sample data what exactly you want to achieve. Also post structure how It is now and how It should be. For now is hard to understand what you really need.